# How to get element of array with string index path

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing

I have an array and I have a path to a specific element.

```
const str = "[0].subArray[2]"

const arr = [
  { subArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, 
  { subArray: [32, 321, 11]}
];
```

Is it possible somehow to display an element using a string path?

Comment: not recommended for security concerns, but would work: `eval("arr"+str)`

Comment: There is a thing called [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) too.

Comment: How are you getting that string in the first place? It seems like this is the result of other problems earlier in the project.

Comment: lots of split() and regex might help :P

Comment: Is the string always going to be of that exact format or can it vary?

Comment: String can be longer, but always is "subArray" for example "[0].subArray[2].subArray[1].subArray[4].subArray[1]"

Comment: If the property is always called "subArray" then there is no need to parse it out: `const getValue = (object, path) => path.match(/\d+/g).reduce((acc, idx, i) => i ? acc.subArray[idx] : acc[idx], object);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach for an length of the path.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .replace(/\[/g, '.')
        .replace(/\]/g, '')
        .split('.')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);
}

console.log(getValue([{ subArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { subArray: [32, 321, 11] }], "[0].subArray[2]"));
```

Comment: But how I can replace this element? The element which we found from the getValue function.

Comment: you could store the array of keys and pop the last key for using with the latest object as property accessor.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result with [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

use regex here

```
/[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/g
```

---

```js
const str = "[0].subArray[2]";

const arr = [{ subArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { subArray: [32, 321, 11] }];

function getValue(arr) {
  const [first, prop, index] = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/g);
  return arr[first][prop][index];
}

const result = getValue(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the key values out of the string using replace with a regex for numbers only, then reconstruct an array to output the sections of your sub-arrays you are targeting using a conditional to check the index to locate array and sub-array keys/values.

```js
const arr = [
  { subArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, 
  { subArray: [32, 321, 11]}
];

const str1 = "[0].subArray[2].subArray[1].subArray[4].subArray[1]" 
const str2 = "[1].subArray[2].subArray[0]" 

function removeNums(val){
  return val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
}

function getArrayValues(str){
  // create an array by splitting the string at the dots
  const arrs = str.split('.')
  const results = []
  for(let i in arrs){
    // get the first index to locate the proper subarray
    // remove all but numbers from the indexes
    const firstIndex = removeNums(arrs[0])
    // skip the first index and get remaining indexes 
    // to get the rest of the subarrays values
    if(i > 0){
      // remove all but numbers from the indexes
      const index = removeNums(arrs[i])
      // construct an array of the proper values
      results.push(arr[firstIndex].subArray[index])
    }
  }
  return results
}

console.log(getArrayValues(str1))
console.log(getArrayValues(str2))
```